# How many pages did Terry's book previously have?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that Terry has a math book, and he starts removing equally many page leaves from the front and back of the book. On the remaining $10$ page leaves, the page numbers sum up to $930$. How many pages did this book previously have?

If we denote the final page number by $n$, then we are removing $1, 2, ..., k$ (front) and $m,\cdots ,n$ (back) from $1,\cdots ,n$ (whole pages), so

$$(k+1)+(k+2)+\cdots + (m-1) = 930$$

If each page leaf contains $2$ pages, then $10$ page leafs contains $20$ pages, hence $(m-1)-(k+1) + 1 = 20$ and $m = k+21$. Re-writing our sum,

$$(k+1)+(k+2)+\cdots + (k+20) = 20k + \frac{20\times 21}{2} = 930$$

So we can see that $k = 36$, so this means $\frac{k}{2} = 18$ pages leaves. Finally, since we removed equally many page leaves from the front and back of the book, it should be true that

$$\frac{1}{2}(n-m+1) = 18\implies n-56 = 36\implies n = 92$$

Thus, the book previously had $92$ pages. However, I can't say I am fairly sure about it. What do you think?

Comment: I think you have some confusion between paper leaf counts and page numbers. Which sort are $k$ and $m$?

Comment: @aschepler $k$ and $m$ are supposed to be some page number.

Comment: Welcome to MSC! What is your question?

Comment: I updated the question. Hopefully, it is more clear now.

Comment: Your answer seems correct and your reasoning is sound.